# What is the best way to make android network calls to my server?

Tags: android, sockets, asynchronous, networking

I have a desktop server in java. I want to connect to server from android and get list of files and display it. Connection uses simply text and binary streams. It's not HTTP. I want to create many metods like listFiles, sendFile etc., but creating AsyncTask for every metod is uncomfortable. What is the best way?

Comment: You can try rxjava for some cleaner code but the learning curve for rxjava is pretty steep

Comment: retrofit will help you .. You should try retrofit

Comment: Can I use retrofit without HTTP server?

Comment: I have simply socket, not HTTP.